# docker login unknown flag "_" underscore

Tags: docker

The command:

```sh
docker login -u _ -p $HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN registry.heroku.com
```

is not equivalent to:

```sh
docker login -u registry.heroku.com -p $HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN
```

How does the underscore syntax works? References?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_` is a username. Heroku must be able to auth you from just the auth token. Docker should not be trying to interpret the argument as a new flag.

Try the long form arguments, they might parse differently:

```
docker login --username=_ --password=$HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN registry.heroku.com
```